# Is there a single word that means "upsert or delete"?

Tags: relational-database, sql-delete, terminology, upsert

I've written a function that upserts a row in to my database and deletes it if it's blank. I'm struggling to name it. If it only upserted, I'd just call it that. And if it only deleted, I'd just call it that. Like how "upsert" combines "update" and "insert", is there a word that includes "delete" in that grouping?

Comment: Is it MERGE? [Merge in SQL](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-statement-sql-explained/)

Comment: @Arul I've not called `MERGE`.